# Changing UserControl background based on SelectedValue from combobox

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, user-controls, datatrigger

What I try to do: I have a list of person profiles in the background that I use with my combobox. The trigger is to change the background based on the gender of the person (bool Role.IsFemale). When I handle the SelectionChangedEvent in the code, I can see the Selectedvalue is true or false. I could now change the background directly or change a dependencyProperty to which the usercontrol itself could listen and change the background when triggered. However, what I try is to just use xaml to achieve this, but nothing happens when I use the code below...

```
<UserControl ...
MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100" x:Name="Crtl">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="windowBGBrush1" Color="Green"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="windowBGBrush2" Color="Red"/>
</UserControl.Resources> 
<UserControl.Style >
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, ElementName=cbProfiles}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource windowBGBrush1}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, ElementName=cbProfiles}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource windowBGBrush2}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Name="cbProfiles" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Role.RoleID" SelectedValuePath="Role.IsFemale"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="spFileInfo" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=cbProfiles, Path=SelectedItem}">
        <TextBlock>Selected:</TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbFileFolder" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Text="{Binding Path=Role.RoleID}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your Xaml and it works fine for me, when I change the combo box, it changes the background. Perhaps there is something wrong with your data binding. I used the following data structure

```
class Role
{
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public bool IsFemale { get; set; }

    public Role() {}
}

class Person
{
    public Role Role { get; set; }

    public Person() {}
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried it myself in a new project and added my code to the main window directly: It works, the background changes! 
Before I used a UserControl and added this control to the window. I see the control and can use it, but the background does not change. 

Anybody able to explain that behavior? Would be interesting for me, as I very often develop UserControls that I can reuse in different projects...

Comment: Something is messed with that UserControl then, because I actually tested your Xaml in one of my projects, inside a UserControl